# Highchart, One column as background for another

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There is the code http://jsfiddle.net/M4FPz/

```
$(function(){new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo:'shopperschart_container', height: 460, zoomType: 'xy' }, 
    credits: { enabled: false }, 
    title: { text: '' }, 
    xAxis: { categories: ['April - 2014', 'May - 2014'] }, 
    yAxis: [{ labels: { enabled: false, style: { color: '#89A54E' } }, min: 0, opposite: true, title: { style: { color: '#89A54E' }, text: '' } }, { gridLineWidth: 0, labels: { enabled: true, style: { color: '#4572A7' } }, min: 0, title: { style: { color: '#4572A7' }, text: 'Visitors' } }, { gridLineWidth: 0, labels: { enabled: false, style: { color: '#AA4643' } }, min: 0, opposite: true, title: { style: { color: '#AA4643' }, text: '' } }, { gridLineWidth: 0, labels: { enabled: false, style: { color: '#FF8B00' } }, min: 0, opposite: true, title: { style: { color: '#FF8B00' }, text: '' } }, { gridLineWidth: 0, labels: { enabled: true, style: { color: '#FF8B00' } }, min: 0, opposite: true, title: { style: { color: '#FF8B00' }, text: 'Mrm' } }], 
    series: [{ data: [160557, 33110], name: 'Input', stack: 'Input', type: 'column', yAxis: 1 }, { data: [174217, 34888], name: 'Output', stack: 'Output', type: 'column', yAxis: 1 }, { data: [235656, 1000417.0000], name: 'Mrm', type: 'column', yAxis: 4, color: 'rgba(30, 144, 255, .5)', zIndex:-1, grouping:false, pointPadding: 0.1, groupPadding: 0, borderWidth: 0 }]
});});
```

As you can see, there is the wrong offset for third column (background). It shows 'April' column in 'May' column.

Could you pleas help me with that ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Well, wrong offset is illustrated on [this](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s40/sh/a1e6664d-c72c-45a4-b669-ea0916d18c7f/16f04b8ca056e7e66b7c2b24e751a4f6)

**EDIT**

According to answer @SebastianBochan, the solution is  [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/M4FPz/6/). Also my question was duplicated on [Highchart forum](http://forum.highcharts.com/post103706.html#p103706)

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle where the code is actually readable: http://jsfiddle.net/M4FPz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You disabled `grouping`, by parameter so it is moved to last element. Try to disable it

http://jsfiddle.net/M4FPz/2/

Comment: Yep, I understand that behavior as you mentioned. But I need that the last column (light-blue) will behind the another columns. Exactly as I show in my example (but there is wrong offset)

Comment: @Mark, sorry for misunderstanding, I have updated my question. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: You can try to use pointWidth and place your backgorund series as second. http://jsfiddle.net/M4FPz/4/

Comment: @SebastianBochan, Great ! It is perfect ! Thank you very much. I just need to change the order of series in array. It is http://jsfiddle.net/M4FPz/6/